# Recode subset of variables using case when in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case, recode

I am trying to recode some survey data in R. Here is some data similar to what I actually have.

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = rep("Y",5),
  B=seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-13"), as.POSIXct("2014-01-17"), by="days"),
  C = c("Neither agree nor disagree",
        "Somewhat agree",
        "Somewhat disagree",
        "Strongly agree",
        "Strongly disagree"),
  D=c("Neither agree nor disagree",
         "Somewhat agree",
         "Somewhat disagree",
         "Strongly agree",
         "Strongly disagree")
)
```

I looked up some other posts and wrote the code below:

```
init2<-df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c(1:4)), function(x) case_when( x == "Neither agree nor disagree" ~ 3, 
                                     x == "Somewhat agree" ~ 4, 
                                     x == "Somewhat disagree"~ 2,
                                     x== "Strongly agree"~ 5,
                                     x== "Strongly disaagree"~ 1
                                     
                                     ))
```

But this throws the error

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `B`.
i `B = (function (x) ...`.
x character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

My input dates are POSIXct. SHould I change their format? What is the fix for this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to try to recode `POSIXt` columns to your Likert scale; nor does it make sense to me to try to recode the `"Y"` column, though at least you are not getting an error about that.

I suggest you either:

1. Explicitly `mutate` the columns you want,

   ```r
   df %>%
     mutate(across(c(C, D), ~ case_when(
       . == "Neither agree nor disagree" ~ 3,
       . == "Somewhat agree"             ~ 4,
       . == "Somewhat disagree"          ~ 2,
       . == "Strongly agree"             ~ 5,
       . == "Strongly disagree"          ~ 1
     )))
   #   A          B C D
   # 1 Y 2014-01-13 3 3
   # 2 Y 2014-01-14 4 4
   # 3 Y 2014-01-15 2 2
   # 4 Y 2014-01-16 5 5
   # 5 Y 2014-01-17 1 1
   ```
2. Explicitly *exclude* columns you don't want,

   ```r
   df %>%
     mutate(across(-c(A, B), ~ case_when(
       . == "Neither agree nor disagree" ~ 3,
       . == "Somewhat agree"             ~ 4,
       . == "Somewhat disagree"          ~ 2,
       . == "Strongly agree"             ~ 5,
       . == "Strongly disagree"          ~ 1
     )))
   ```
3. Conditionally process them via some filter (though this is not infallible):

   ```r
   df %>%
     mutate(across(where(~ all(grepl("agree", .))), ~ case_when(
       . == "Neither agree nor disagree" ~ 3,
       . == "Somewhat agree"             ~ 4,
       . == "Somewhat disagree"          ~ 2,
       . == "Strongly agree"             ~ 5,
       . == "Strongly disagree"          ~ 1
     )))
   ```

FYI, according to https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html (on 2021 Nov 7):

> Scoped verbs (`_if`, `_at`, `_all`) have been superseded by the use of `across()` in an existing verb. See `vignette("colwise")` for details.

It pairs nicely with [`where`](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/where.html), provided (surreptitiously) by the `tidyselect` package.

Comment: So the case_when tries to recode variables like the Date variable which don't have the target values? I thought it would automatically exclude variables which don't have the "Agree/Disagree" type input. Thanks.

Comment: And the grepl filters those variables which have the "Agree" in their values?

Comment: (1) Recoding the *string* `"2014-01-13"` from one of your Likert scale is always going to produce `NA`s, which does not seem the prudent way to go. (2) Recoding a *number-like column* (both `POSIXt` and `Date` are stored as numbers internally) against strings is an error due to the class-breach. (3) Yes, `grepl` is looking for the literal `"agree"` in the recoding strings. This was an inference based on the values you provided here, you may choose to update it, perhaps with `ignore.case=TRUE` or other safeguards.